# How can I prompt a user for a comment when using a batch file to commit to a GIT repository?

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, comments

I have found a way to streamline git by using batch files but it forces me to bypass an important step. Using this batch file I cannot stop and prompt the user for a comment on the commit. Does anyone know how I can pause the batch file and wait for a string that will be the comment on the commit?

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /c/users/...
git add *edited file*
git commit -m %Comment%
git push
echo Press Enter...
read
```

Comment: You've tagged this as `windows`, but that is a POSIX script you have there.  Which do you want?

Comment: It seems to be using cygwin or Git Shell or anything like that (see that `/c/users/` path).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not adding the `-m` switch to the `git commit` command?

It should launch your default text editor (as set in `$EDITOR` environment variable - run `echo $EDITOR` to know your's, but probably is notepad or vim) asking the user for a commit message.

That's the default `git commit` behaviour - that `-m` switch is a shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shell script:

```
read Comment
git commit -m "$Comment"
```

If you need a Windows BAT script:

```
set /p Comment="Comment: "
git commit -m "%Comment%"
```